# Range-slider control

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is a good kind of a `range-slider` control http://makescreen.ru/i/50c4af7ae3a9058a7f551d398ccecf.jpg

I'd like to use something similar for my project. But I didn't find anything. It would be better if this control exists for twitter bootstrap. If it doesn't, anything similar would be ok.

Your ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [jQuery UI](http://addyosmani.github.com/jquery-ui-bootstrap/) (linked version specifically for twitter bootstrap) - they have everything you could ever need for javascript UI elements.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is a couple of months old and already has an accepted answer, but I just came across this as well:

http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/

and it seems relevant to the discussion.